# Как нужно изменить Linq-запрос, чтобы выводились сначала 10, потом 8, потом 6, далее остальное

Tags: c#, linq

```
class A
    {
        int[] arr;

        public A(int[] array)
        {
            arr = array;
        }

        public A(int count)
        {
            arr = GenerateArray(count);
        }

        private static int[] GenerateArray(int count)
        {
            var array = new int[count];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = rnd.Next(4, 11);
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
            }

            return array;

        }

        public void Linq()
        {
// эту строчку нужно поменять так, чтобы выполнялось  условие задания. В данном случае выводятся сначала  шестерки, восьмерки, десятки в произвольном  порядке, потом все остальное. А надо, чтобы сначала десятки, потом восьмерки, потом шестерки, потом все остальное

            var result = arr.OrderByDescending(c => c == 10 || c == 8 || c == 6);
                                   
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

        }

    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A st1 = new A(20);
            Console.WriteLine(st1);
            st1.Linq();

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, занятие по сортировке? И вам нужна специальная

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: да, спасибо, удалось

Comment: Ответ удален, потому что не был принят вами как полезный.